# Is there a word for the word being described by an adjective?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Is there a word for the word being described by an adjective? In other words, the "target" of an adjective. Or, by analogy, "Operators have *operands*, adjectives have ____."

Comment: [Related and possible duplicate](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/417271/2085).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word ***modificand*** exists as a term of art for the thing you are looking for, and means according to the OED, “something that is to be modified.”  But it is not particularly common:

> A. 1832 Bentham *Language Wks.* 1843 VIII. 317/2 ― In this way, modificative clauses in any number may be made to precede, and by that means exclusively attach upon one and the same modificand.

The problem with just calling it a noun or noun phrase is that when you have something like

> my earlier someone

(Which I would still call an NP, mind you), then the adjective *earlier* is targeting a pronoun, not a noun, and the possessive determiners *my* falls in the normal slot in an NP, despite it having a pronoun not a noun at its head.

Comment: That's funny. I initially wrote _modificand_ as a made-up example, but decided to write an analogy instead. Thanks!

Comment: Regard all pronouns as nouns, as some do, and any problem of demarcation disappears.

Comment: Analogies are more normal than the use of uncommon words. By definition, practically.

Answer (score 1):

The word is *noun* or *noun phrase*.

Comment: It is a *noun* or *noun phrase*, but that doesn't describe its relationship to the adjective.